# Cypress resolving elements and asserting "not to exist" with custom commands?

Tags: cypress

I'm struggling to understand why the following (simplified version of) piece of code doesn't work. If I do:

```
cy.get('#doesntexist').should(elem => {expect(elem).not.to.exist})
```

This works fine. But if I have a custom command:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("checknotthere", { prevSubject: false }, (subject) => {
subject.should(elem => {expect(elem).not.to.exist})
})
// and call that with:
cy.checknotthere(cy.get('#doesntexist')
```

This fails with "Cannot set property 'err' of undefined"

Similarly the following fails in the same way:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("checknotthere", { prevSubject: false }, (subject) => {
expect(subject).not.to.exist
})
//Call the above with:
cy.get('#doesntexist').should(elem => {cy.checknotthere(elem)})
```

What is it about putting the non-existence assertion into a custom command that breaks things - regardless of whether I try to resolve the element inside, or outside the custom command code? Any other assertions (exists, is visible, contains etc) seem fine...) As I say, the above example is simplified, even trivialised compared to my actual custom command - but I just wanted to illustrate the problem - please don't ask why I want a custom command just to assert an element isn't there, I don't - there's more to it than that!

Comment: I think this is related to retries cypress does for `get` and some chained commands. Instead of passing element to the command, you could pass selector and do the get within the custom command, e.g. `cy.get(elementSelector).should(elem => {expect(elem).not.to.exist})`

Comment: I think you are probably right. The frustrating thing is that sort of scuppers my plans to use page objects - I could change all my page object definitions to just return the selector as a string, instead of using cy.get and returning the element - but that would have implications for other references (not just my custom cmd!) to the elements.... I'll give it a go though, see what happens! :)

Comment: So it seems it's nothing to do with my element resolution, or my custom command. Even the following fails in the same way ```cy.get('#doesntexist').should(elem => {cy.log('hello')})```

Comment: This works `cy.get('#doesntexist').should('not.exist');`